# How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in JPA Custom Query

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

> I want to update work_withdraw table .My aim to perform update select
> function at a same time.I want to set my Deposit table pending column
> data in work_withdraw quantity column , when user call the update api

.enter image description here

[image]

[image]

> I want to set pending data in work_withdraw  table quantity column.
> Here is my query But I am not able to update work_withdraw table
> through using JPA query
> DepositRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.repository

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Deposit
import com.nilmani.workload.entity.WorkWithdraw
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam

interface DepositRepository:JpaRepository<Deposit,Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update Ww SET Ww .quantity = d .pending FROM WorkWithdraw AS Ww INNER JOIN  Deposit AS d  ON Ww.id = d.id")
    fun getPendingStatus(@RequestParam("id")id: WorkWithdraw):Long

}
```

> I want update the table worker_withdraw automatically when admin enter
> the worker_withdraw id
> But My query Not existing as what Type of Result I want

Answer (score 1):

JPA doesn't support update join syntax the way that many SQL databases do.  Instead, you may use a subquery:

```java
update WorkWithdraw ww
set ww.quantity = (select d.pending from Deposit d where d.id = ww.id);
```